# How to capture a blank slug value in a django url pattern?

Tags: django

I know I can do this with `re_path`, but is there a way to make a slug optional in a URL? Something like:

```
path("issues/<int:pk>/<optional-slug:slug>/")
```

I'm working on upgrading to Django 2.0, and trying to remove as many of my old-style, regex-based `url` patterns as possible.

Comment: Just create two paths, one with the slug and one without

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to register a "converter". There are some docs about it here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#registering-custom-path-converters

In this instance, you put something like this in your root urls.py file (not necessarily the one where you want to use it):

```py
from myproject.lib.converters import BlankSlugConverter
register_converter(BlankSlugConverter, "blank-slug")
```

Then in converters.py, you put:

```py
from django.urls.converters import StringConverter


class BlankSlugConverter(StringConverter):
    """A slug converter that allows blank values

    This just swapped out the plus sign in the SlugConverter for an asterisk.
    """

    regex = "[-a-zA-Z0-9_]*"
```

And in your urls.py pattern, you can do:

```
path("issues/<int:pk>/<blank-slug:slug>/")
```

And that's it! No need for an additional import or anything in that urls.py file. The `register_converter` call makes it available everywhere.